# datepicker is not a function laravel jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

Laravel includes jquery in laravel mix. But when I add:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
} );
```

in my app.js it tells me .datepicker is not defined. However I tried including

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

In my layout.blade.html but wether I remove it or not it keeps saying its not defined.

My html:

```
<label for="model">APK</label>              
    <input type="text" name="apk" class="form-control" placeholder="apk" id="datepicker">
</label>
```

Comment: are you using class datepicker in your input,
i suggest to use jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});

Comment: do you apply the configuration in this page:
https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/docs/jquery-ui.md

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
} ); changing it to that doesnt matter

Comment: Sounds like you are loading  jQuery.js more than once  in page. A second load will wipe out plugins registered to the first